# JSQMessageViewController - JSQAudioMediaItem why multiple audio files playing simelteneously

Tags: ios, iphone, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[image]

i have implemented JSQMessageViewController and added JSQAudioMediaItem for handling audio files but when i have play one audio and play another audio. both are playing simelteneously. Previous audio file does not stop playing. how i can achieve only single audio file is play at a time.

Comment: you will need to probably listen to the media delegate which will tell you if its playback was started. You can then instruct the other visible cells to pause or stop playback.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own subclass of 'NSAudioPlayer' and entire only one audio stream at a time by using a shared instance of it.